# Tokio Tls Self Signed Certificate

Tags: ssl, rust, rust-tokio

Update: This seems to be more of an issue with generating and trusting a self signed cert properly

I am building a server and client using tokio-rs. I have everything working but am now trying to add SSL/TLS to the system. I've generated a self signed certificate and installed it correctly as far as I know, but every time I try to get the client to connect to the server I get the following error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Failure(Ssl(ErrorStack([Error { code: 336134278, library: "SSL routines", function: "ssl3_get_server_certificate", reason: "certificate verify failed", file: "s3_clnt.c", line: 1264 }])))', /buildslave/rust-buildbot/slave/stable-dist-rustc-linux/build/src/libcore/result.rs:837
```

I am using the following script to generate a crt, key and pfx file:

```
openssl req -nodes -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -config ssl.conf -extensions ext -subj /C=CA/ST=EH/L=Canadia/O=Dis/CN=localhost -keyout localhost.key -out localhost.crt -days 365
openssl pkcs12 -export -nodes -inkey localhost.key -in localhost.crt -out localhost.pfx
mv localhost.pfx ../
```

with this conf file

```
[req]
distinguished_name=dn
[ dn ]
CN=localhost
[ ext ]
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE,pathlen:0
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost
```

The pfx file is moved up a level and then copied into the debug folder on build.

I am running Ubuntu and have copied localhost.crt to /etc/ssl/certs and localhost.key to /etc/ssl/private

My server code is using tokio-proto and the tokio-tls tokio-proto Server protocol wrapper

Protocol:

```
use tokio_proto::pipeline::ServerProto;
use tokio_io::codec::{Framed};
use tokio_io::{AsyncRead, AsyncWrite};
use tokio_tls::{TlsAcceptorExt};
use rem::codec::CacheCodec;
use std::io;

pub struct CacheProto {}

impl<T: AsyncRead + AsyncWrite + 'static> ServerProto<T> for CacheProto {
    /// For this protocol style, `Request` matches the codec `In` type
    type Request = String;

    /// For this protocol style, `Response` matches the coded `Out` type
    type Response = String;

    /// A bit of boilerplate to hook in the codec:
    type Transport = Framed<T, CacheCodec>;
    type BindTransport = Result<Self::Transport, io::Error>;
    fn bind_transport(&self, io: T) -> Self::BindTransport {
        Ok(io.framed(CacheCodec{}))
    }
}
```

Server:

```
use std::string::String;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

use rem::cache::Cache;
use rem::service::CacheService;
use rem::proto::CacheProto;

use futures_cpupool::CpuPool;

use tokio_tls::{TlsAcceptorExt};
use native_tls::{Pkcs12, TlsAcceptor};

use tokio_tls::proto::Server;
use tokio_proto::TcpServer;

use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{Read};

pub fn launch(ip: String, port: String) {
   // Specify the localhost address
    let addr = format!("{}:{}", ip, port).parse().unwrap();

    let pkcs12 = get_pkcs12();
    let acceptor = TlsAcceptor::builder(pkcs12).unwrap().build().unwrap();

    let proto = Server::new(CacheProto{}, acceptor);

    // The builder requires a protocol and an address
    let server = TcpServer::new(proto, addr);

    let pool = Box::new(CpuPool::new_num_cpus());

    // We provide a way to *instantiate* the service for each new
    // connection; here, we just immediately return a new instance.
    let cache = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Cache::new()));
    let cache_service = CacheService {
        cache: cache.clone(),
        pool : pool
    };

    server.serve( move || Ok(cache_service.clone()));
}

fn get_pkcs12() -> Pkcs12{
    let mut file = File::open("localhost.pfx").unwrap();
    let mut pkcs12 = vec![];
    file.read_to_end(&mut pkcs12).unwrap();
    let pkcs12 = Pkcs12::from_der(&pkcs12, "password").unwrap();
    return pkcs12;
}
```

Client: (Not using tokio-proto, just native tls and TCP)

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::io;
use std::string::String;
use std::vec::Vec;
use std::net::{TcpStream};
use std::mem;

use native_tls::{TlsConnector, TlsStream};

use rem::op;
use rem::error::*;

pub fn launch(ip: String, port: String) {
    info!("Connection to {}:{}", ip, port);

    match TcpStream::connect(format!("{}:{}", ip, port).as_str()) {
        Ok(mut tcp_stream) => {
            let connector = TlsConnector::builder().unwrap().build().unwrap();
            let mut stream = connector.connect(ip.as_str(), tcp_stream).unwrap();
            loop {
                // Contine looping, executing any commands from the user
                let handle = io::stdin();
                for line_res in handle.lock().lines() {
                    let line: String = line_res.unwrap();
                    let args:Vec<String> = parse_input(line);
                    if args.len() > 0{
                        let arg_ref = args[0].as_ref();
                        match arg_ref {
                            "write" => {
                                if args.len() == 3 {
                                    match client_exec_write(&args[1], &args[2], &mut stream){
                                        Ok(_) => (),
                                        Err(why) => why.log()
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    error!("Write expects two arguments - key and value");
                                }
                            },
                            "read" => {
                                if args.len() == 2 {
                                    match client_exec_read(&args[1], &mut stream){
                                        Ok(_) => (),
                                        Err(why) => why.log()
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    error!("Read expects one argument - key");
                                }
                            },
                            "delete" => {
                                if args.len() == 2 {
                                    match client_exec_delete(&args[1], &mut stream){
                                        Ok(_) => (),
                                        Err(why) => why.log()
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    error!("Delete expects one argument - key");
                                }
                            }
                            _ => error!("Not a valid command")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Err(e) => {
            panic!("Failed to connect to server. Error '{}'", e);
        }
    }
}


/// Executres a write operation by parsing the client command and converting it to REM format
/// ex: write abc:def would be converted to 9|W$abc:def and sent to the REM server
fn client_exec_write(key:&String, val:&String, mut stream: &mut TlsStream<TcpStream>)-> Result<(), RemError> {
    let sized_val = String::from(format!("W${}:{}", key, val));
    let res = op::write_str_to_stream_with_size(&mut stream, sized_val);
    try!(print_response(&mut stream));
    return res;
}

/// Executres a read operation by parsing the client command and converting it to REM format
/// ex: read abc:def would be converted to 5|R$abc and sent to the REM launch_server
/// The respone from the REM server is writen to stdout
/// If stdout::flush fail a warning will be logged
fn client_exec_read(key: &String, mut stream: &mut TlsStream<TcpStream>)-> Result<(), RemError>{
    let cmd_val = String::from(format!("R${}", key));
    try!(op::write_str_to_stream_with_size(&mut stream, cmd_val));
    try!(print_response(&mut stream));
    return Ok(());
}

/// Executes a delete operation by parsing the client command and converting it to REM format
/// ex: delete abc would be converted to 5|D$abc and sent to the REM server
fn client_exec_delete(key: &String, mut stream: &mut TlsStream<TcpStream>) -> Result<(), RemError>{
    let cmd_val = String::from(format!("D${}", key));
    let res = op::write_str_to_stream_with_size(&mut stream, cmd_val);
    try!(print_response(&mut stream));
    return res;
}

fn print_response(mut stream: &mut TlsStream<TcpStream>) -> Result<(), RemError>{
    let val: String = try!(op::string_from_stream(&mut stream));
    println!("{}", val);
    try!(io::stdout().flush());
    return Ok(());
}

struct InputParser{
    args:Vec<String>,
    current:String,
    consumed_double_quote:bool,
    consumed_single_quote:bool
}

impl InputParser{

    /// Consumes a space charater taking quotes into consideration
    /// If the parser has consumed an opening quote then the space will be consumed as a character
    pub fn consume_space(&mut self){
        // If neither a single quote or a double quote has been consumed then its a new argument
        if !self.consumed_double_quote && !self.consumed_single_quote {
            self.push_current();
        }else{
            self.current.push(' ');
        }
    }

    /// Consumes a double quote, keeping track of whether it is an opening or cloing quote
    /// Takes single quotes into account when determening if the double quote is a delimiter or character
    pub fn consume_double_quote(&mut self){
        // If a single quote hasn't been consumed we're at the end or 
        // beginning of an argument in double quotes
        if  !self.consumed_single_quote {
            if self.consumed_double_quote{
                self.push_current();
            }
            // Flip the value so we know the sate for the next double quote that is consumed
            self.consumed_double_quote = !self.consumed_double_quote;
        }else{
            // If we're in double quotes just treat the double quote as a regular character 
            self.current.push('"');
        }
    }

    /// Consumes a single quote, keeping track of whether it is an opening or cloing quote
    /// Takes double quotes into account when determening if the single quote is a delimiter or character
    pub fn consume_single_quote(&mut self){
         // If a double quote hasn't been consumed we're at the end or 
        // beginning of an argument in single quotes
         if !self.consumed_double_quote {
            if self.consumed_single_quote{
                self.push_current();
            }
            // Flip the value so we know the sate for the next single quote that is consumed
            self.consumed_single_quote = !self.consumed_single_quote;
        }else{
            // If we're in double quotes just treat the single quote as a regular character 
            self.current.push('\'');
        }
    }

    /// Adds the character onto the current argument
    pub fn consume_char(&mut self, c:char){
        self.current.push(c);
    }

    /// To be called when everything has been parsed
    pub fn end(&mut self){
        self.push_current();
    }

    /// Pushes the current string into the list of args
    /// If the length of current is 0 no actions are performed
    pub fn push_current(&mut self){
        if self.current.len() > 0 {
            let arg = mem::replace(&mut self.current, String::new());
            self.args.push(arg);
        }
    }

}

/// Parses the arguments out of an input string taking quotes and spaces into consideration
pub fn parse_input(input: String) -> Vec<String>{
    let mut parser = InputParser{
        args:Vec::new(),
        current:String::new(),
        consumed_double_quote:false,
        consumed_single_quote:false
    };    
    for c in input.chars(){
        match c {
            '"'  => parser.consume_double_quote(),
            ' '  => parser.consume_space(),
            '\'' => parser.consume_single_quote(), 
            _    => parser.consume_char(c)
        }
    }
    parser.end();

    return parser.args;
}
```

Op:

````
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::string::String;
use std::vec::Vec;
use std::net::{TcpStream};
use std::sync::{Mutex};

use native_tls::{TlsConnector, TlsStream};

use rem::cache::Cache;
use rem::error::*;


pub fn read_value_from_cache(key: String,
                         cache_mtx: &Mutex<Cache>)
                         -> Result<(Vec<u8>), RemError> {
    let cache = cache_mtx.lock().unwrap();
    let cache_opt: Option<Box<Vec<u8>>> = try!(cache.read_item(key));
    match cache_opt {
        Some(boxed_val) => {
            let val: Vec<u8> = *boxed_val;
            return Ok(val.clone());
        }
        None => {
            return Err(RemError::with_reason(String::from(REM_00005)));
        }
    }
}

/// Parses a TCP input stream and extracts the data
/// Allocates a 64 byte buffer which is used to read the input info from the stream
/// The expected format is ```{size}|{content}```
/// Ex. ```5|W$a:b```
pub fn string_from_stream(stream: &mut TlsStream<TcpStream>) -> Result<String, RemError> {
    //Read in the first 54 bytes of the stram
    //try!(stream.set_nodelay(true));
    let mut buf_arr: [u8; 64] = [0; 64];
    try!(stream.read(&mut buf_arr));
    // Parse the message size
    let mut size_str = String::new();
    let mut buf_size: usize = 0;
    for i in 0..64 {
        buf_size += 1;
        if buf_arr[i] == '|' as u8 {
            break;
        }
        size_str.push(buf_arr[i as usize] as char);
    }

    // Convert the size string to a usize so it can be used to drain the buffer
    let upper_idx: usize = try!(size_str.parse::<i32>()) as usize;
    let mut buf_temp: Vec<u8> = buf_arr.to_vec();
    // Create a new buffer using the parsed indicies
    let buf: Vec<u8> = buf_temp.drain(buf_size..upper_idx + buf_size).collect();

    stream.flush().unwrap();

    // Return the value as a string
    let buf_str: String = String::from_utf8(buf).unwrap();
    return Ok(buf_str);
}

pub fn write_stream_str_to_cache(stream_str: String,
                             cache_mtx: &Mutex<Cache>)
                             -> Result<(), RemError> {
    let mut key: String = String::new();
    let mut val: String = String::new();
    let mut idx = 0;
    let chars_iter = stream_str.chars();
    for c in chars_iter {
        idx += 1;
        if c == ':' {
            val = String::from(&stream_str[idx..]);
            break;
        }
        key.push(c);
    }
    let bytes = val.into_bytes();
    let mut cache = cache_mtx.lock().unwrap();
    return cache.cache_item(key.as_str(), bytes);
}

pub fn delete_value_from_cache(key: String, cache_mtx: &Mutex<Cache>) -> Result<(), RemError> {
    let mut cache = cache_mtx.lock().unwrap();
    return cache.delete_item(key);
}

pub fn write_str_to_stream_with_size(stream: &mut TlsStream<TcpStream>, value: String) -> Result<(), RemError> {
    let sized_val = String::from(format!("{}|{}", value.len(), value));
    try!(stream.write(String::from(sized_val).as_bytes()));
    try!(stream.flush());
    return Ok(());
}
````

There are more files to this project but I don't think they're relevant, however I can add them if things are unclear

Comment: *I can add them if things are unclear* — have you tried **removing** things? For example, I strongly doubt that having a thread pool on the server side has any effect on the SSL, nor should `consume_single_quote` and probably lots of other parts. In fact, having all of these makes it *harder* to see the problem. Please review what a [MCVE] is and why it benefits not only potential answerers but also yourself.

Comment: I'd also suggest adding a bit of text on exactly *why* you think that the error you are getting is invalid.

Comment: Continuing in the removal direction, what about removing tokio completely? I'd be surprised if this had anything directly to do with tokio, and think that you could probably just set up a a TCP socket with TLS and then try connecting to it.

Comment: You may also wish to use a tool like `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.domain.com:443` to validate that your server is or is not working, which will allow you to decide if the server or client is at fault.

Comment: That seems to work so I guess it's the client. I get the following response  https://pastebin.com/xeXAvrzx

Comment: Looking at it closer it does seem to be throwing a verification error `verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more an OpenSSL issue than a Rust issue. Assuming the client is running Ubuntu also, copy the `*.crt` file to its `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/`, then run `sudo /usr/sbin/update-ca-certificates`. That will tell the client to trust your certificate, and OpenSSL will no longer report an error about it.

(Edit:) You still have a remaining problem, which is that the cert's Common Name (CN) does not match the name the client is using to reach the server. Your `ssl.conf` gives it a CN of `localhost`, but the client asks for it by IP. Obviously if the client asks for https://localhost/ it's not going to work. So you should re-generate your cert with a different DNS name, have the client trust the new cert, and then use that name for making requests. If necessary you could just use a name like `rustsslserver` and put that in your client's `/etc/hosts`.

I have [a git repo that shows a working example here](https://github.com/pjungwir/rust-ssl-self-signed). Note it uses hyper, not tokio, but the results should be the same.

Comment: I did that and running SSL connect no longer shows the self signed cert error. I still get the same error when trying to connect using my client. Would the rust openssl crate know about these new certs?

Comment: The rust crate is just wrapping the C OpenSSL library. Did you do anything special to build the openssl crate, like point it at a custom compiled `libssl`? By default it should just use your `libssl-dev` apt package. You might want to spin up a fresh Ubuntu VM, `sudo apt-get libssl-dev`, install the cert there per my instructions, build your project there, and see if it works.

Comment: It got compiled through cargo so I would assume it should be correct. I'll try clearing out all the complied cargo stuff to see if that helps. If not I could try a vm

Comment: Okay, good luck! If you are doing things like [setting envvars to find openssl](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl#manual-configuration) then I would be suspicious there are two versions installed: the distro library that looks in the standard place for trusted certs, and another one that looks elsewhere.

Comment: Oh another thing: in the past I have gotten errors about `openssl-sys`, but the fix was simply `sudo apt-get install pkg-config` (so cargo could find the already-installed libssl), not anything more involved. I just mention it in case that was causing you to use a self-compiled copy.

Comment: Okay, I added notes to my answer fixing a second problem (CN mismatch), as well as a link to a working example on github. Let me know if that doesn't fix the problem for you!

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll give it a shot in a couple hours and reply back

Comment: So I've gotten openssl and curl to connect without complaining but still no luck with my rust client. https://github.com/RyanBluth/rem/blob/master/script/gencert.sh   I'm running that script to do everything with the certs but still get the same error. I'm using remdev as the domain and have added it to my hosts like so "127.0.0.1      remdev"

Comment: I cloned your repo and got it working. On line 16 of `client.rs` you changed the code to ignore the `ip` param and use the hardcoded string `"remdev"` instead. But you must *also* change line 19, because that is where you tell the SSL system whom you think you're talking to. Passing the IP there causes the CN mismatch.

Comment: Sorry about that, I actually noticed that as well and changed it after committing. I'll check it again. Did you use my script to create the cert?

Comment: Yes, I ran `gencert.sh`. I did notice that I had to manually copy the pfx file into `target` though. Also, watch out with `update-ca-certificates`. I think if the filename is already present, it won't update it. So if it says `0 added`, your new cert hasn't been registered. But in that case `curl` (with no `-k`) will start failing too.

Comment: Hmm okay, I'll give it another shot. I'm probably missing one little thing, thanks for all the help

Comment: I finally got it to work, I think it was failing to actually update the ca-certs properly when using `/usr/sbin/update-ca-certificates`. I used `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` instead and was able to add the new cert properly

Comment: Hooray! Best of luck with your project. :-)